# How to set different orientation of fragment in activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

In my MainActivity has `fragmentA`, `fragmentB`, `fragmentC`.

I want set `fragmentA` and `fragmentB` orientation to portrait but `fragmentC` to landscape.

If the Manifest is set to portrait like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

all fragment orientations are portrait.

How would I set the different orieantation of each fragment?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use fragmentA and fragmentB when the application orientation is portrait and to use fragmentC when the orientation is landscape ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in `OnCreateView(View view)` of particular fragment,

```
//ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE

  getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

//ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

  getActivity()setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line in oncreate () in fragment A and B

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

and add this line in oncreate() in fragment C

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

its working for me and I hope it will help you!