# Using a deifferent orientation in Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app that has 1 main activity and 8 fragments. In the Manifest file I set the orientation like :

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

For 6 of the 8 fragments this orientation is fine. However I need to change the orientation in just 2 fragments. I have searched and found a couple posts with the same aswer as: [How to set different orientation of fragment in activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820956/how-to-set-different-orientation-of-fragment-in-activity) However when I go to the fragment and use this code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_name, container, false);
    }
```

the app goes back to the first screen with portrait orientation set, like it has restarted the app with a different orientation setting. Every screen opened after this is set in portrait orientation, until I close the app and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete android:screenOrientation="landscape" from Manifest file. After then set SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE or SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT mode for each fragment

Comment: Made these changes, all of the landscape fragments load fine. However the 2 portrait fragments still go back to the first screen, but now it loads in portrait mode.